How to deal with MNAR data based on failures in a trial?
Background
I have a dataset in which participants had to perform a certain task within a time frame. The outcome of this task is not binary, but there was a criterion that should be reached within the time frame to be considered a "successful" trial. Later on, I would like to analyze their performance within this time frame using a linear mixed model.
However, some participants were not able to successfully complete the task within the maximum allowed time frame.
Potential Approaches
I could treat their data as missing data - probably leading to a Missing Not At Random (MNAR)1 missing data pattern (because I would be systematically missing data from participants that are bad in the task). Therefore, I feel like this would not be the best solution.
One other solution would be to treat the successful completion as the actual outcome variable (making it the new performance outcome). But that would leave a lot of information on the table that has already been collected during the trial (turning a metric variable on the performance into a binary one).
On the other end, I could analyze the participants' performance up to the point where the trial ends. This would, however, leave out the fact that some of those trials were not completed successfully.
Question
I am, therefore, looking for pointers on how to deal with MNAR data based on trial performance.

1Clarification for Missing Not At Random (MNAR):
The NIH defines MNAR as:

When data are MNAR, the fact that the data are missing is
systematically related to the unobserved data, that is, the
missingness is related to events or factors which are not measured by
the researcher.[...] As with MAR data, complete case analysis of a
data set containing MNAR data may or may not result in bias; if the
complete case analysis is biased, however, the fact that the sources
of missing data are themselves unmeasured means that (in general) this
issue cannot be addressed in analysis and the estimate of effect will
likely be biased.

In most cases, this refers to data where your response for a certain variable is systematically missing based on the assumed outcome for the variable. In the case above, we are systematically missing performance data for people who (would have) performed poorly.
